# How to highlight and get active state for main navigation menu item and sub navigation menu item on the same page using React Material UI Tabs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router, navigation

In my React `<Header>` component I use [Material UI Tabs](https://v4.mui.com/components/tabs/#tabs) to create a *primary* menu for the main navigation, with react router links instead of showing tab content:

```
    <Tabs value={location.pathname}>
      {(items || []).map((item) => (
        <Tab
          key={item.url}
          label={item.title}
          value={item.url}
          href={item.url}
          disableRipple
        />
      ))}
    </Tabs>
```

On the same page I use Material UI Tabs again for a *secondary* menu.

The route path to the main navigation menu item is: `/example-path`. When I navigate to this route, this menu items is highlighted and has active state.

When the tab of *secondary* menu item with the same route as the highlighted primary menu item `/example-path`, both menu items gets highlighted and active state.

When I click on another *secondary* menu item only this *secondary* menu item gets highlighted `/example-path/tab-two`.

How do I manage both gets highlighted in the same time, The parent from main navigation and the various menu items from the secondary menu?

Comment: What routing/navigation library/package is being used? Can you edit the post to include a more complete [mcve] so it's clearer what the code is trying to do?

Comment: @DrewReese here I made a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tabs-subnavigation-p6zl1p) with the example. When you click on `about`, I want to highlight both `about` and `about sub one` or `about sub two`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Header` component should match on ***only*** the root path segment while the `Submenu` component can compare the complete URL `pathname`. Note that if you've further sub-routes then `Submenu` would need to check the first two segments.

Instead of the `Tab` components rendering a raw anchor tag `<a>` it should render a `Link` component. This is so the router can respond to and handle the navigation action instead of letting the browser make a page request to the server and reload the entire app.

Header

```
import { Tabs, Tab } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Header = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const base = `/${pathname.slice(1).split("/").shift()}`;

  return (
    <Tabs value={base}>
      <Tab component={Link} to="/" label="Home" key="/" value="/" />
      <Tab
        component={Link}
        to="/about"
        label="About"
        key="/about"
        value="/about"
      />
      <Tab
        component={Link}
        to="/dashboard"
        label="Dashboard"
        key="/dashboard"
        value="/dashboard"
      />
    </Tabs>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Submenu

```
import { Tabs, Tab } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Submenu = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  return (
    <Tabs value={pathname}>
      <Tab
        component={Link}
        to="/about/about-one"
        label="About sub one"
        key="1"
        value="/about/about-one"
      />
      <Tab
        component={Link}
        to="/about/about-two"
        label="About sub two"
        key="2"
        value="/about/about-two"
      />
    </Tabs>
  );
};

export default Submenu;
```

App
Order the routes within the `Switch` in *inverse* order of path specificity so that *more* specific paths are matched before falling back to *less* specific paths.

```
<Router>
  <Layout>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/about/about-one">
        <AboutOne />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/about/about-two">
        <AboutTwo />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/about">
        <About />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/dashboard">
        <Dashboard />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/">
        <Home />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Layout>
</Router>
```

[image: Edit how-to-highlight-and-get-active-state-for-main-navigation-menu-item-and-sub-navi]

[image]

Update to handle submenu tabs on the root `"/"` route. For this you'll need to do a bit of a "hack" to check that the URL path ***is not*** one of the other main root routes, so that you can override the base `Tabs` value to be exactly `"/"` instead of one of the `"/home-section/*"` sub-routes, using the `matchPath` utility function.

Example:

```
import { Tabs, Tab } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Link, useLocation, matchPath } from "react-router-dom";

const Header = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const base = `/${pathname.slice(1).split("/").shift()}`;

  const isNotHome = ["/about", "/dashboard"].some((path) =>
    matchPath(pathname, path)
  );

  return (
    <Tabs value={isNotHome ? base : "/"}>
      <Tab component={Link} to="/" label="Home" key="1" value="/" />
      <Tab component={Link} to="/about" label="About" key="2" value="/about" />
      <Tab
        component={Link}
        to="/dashboard"
        label="Dashboard"
        key="3"
        value="/dashboard"
      />
    </Tabs>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: Thanks works fine. Will approve. I have one more edge case. In my main navigation I have a menu item `MyLink` which has `pathname: "/"` (home). In my submenu I have the submenu items `MySubmenuItem` and `MySubmenuItemTwo` which has `pathname: "/my-submenu-item"` and `pathname: "/my-submenu-item/two" `.
How can I force also on home pathname `"/"` the submenu's gets highlighted (or vice versa). Is there somehow a solution for this? Thanks

Comment: @meez Sorry, this is an older answer and for some reason it seems my sandbox no longer exists. Can you fork your sandbox or create a new one with the home `MyLink` and subroutes you are referring to that I could inspect?

Comment: Thanks yes it was a while ago :). Ok here is the new [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/tabs-subnavigation-p6zl1p). Are you able to fork this one? So the edge case is: In my header Home link its `pathname` is `/`. But on that route I need to have the submenu `<SubmenuHome /> with it's routes as defined in my example. As you can see on the About link everything works fine. But only for Home route I need to find a solution. Many thanks

Comment: @meez That sandbox link doesn't seem to work. You might need to mark that sandbox public.

Comment: Ok it's changes to public now. Here the link to the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/tabs-subnavigation-p6zl1p).

Comment: @meez Ok yeah, that's close to the solution path I had sort of re-derived, and you have the same issue I do with the header detecting the home `"/"` path when on one of it's sub-routes that isn't one of the other "main" sub-routes. I think have I have a working solution for this issue. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. On the about route it's working fine because the first tab links to `/about`. So when you access `/about` both main tab and first sub tab gets highlighted. However on the homepage the problem I have is that the first subtab route CAN'T be `"/"`. It has to be something like `/home-section/section-default`. How do I get both tabs highlighted when accessing the homepage? See the [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/tabs-subnavigation-p6zl1p) with updated code. Your solution works _after_ clicking the subnav tabs.

Comment: @meez Because `"/"` isn't *technically* a sub-route like `"/about"`, it needs to be treated as a special case. You've kind of half done this by placing the home page tabs on a `"/home-section"` sub-route, and since it doesn't appear you have any specific content for the `"/"` path you can redirect from `"/"` to `"/home-section/section-default"`, i.e. `<Redirect from="/" exact to="/home-section/section-default" />`, to "bootstrap" the app into the "home page tabs". `SubmenuHome` should then use `value="/home-section/section-default"` for the first tab. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yeah that could be a solution indeed. Is Redirect from React router bad for SEO?

Comment: I don't believe redirecting alone in React-Router is bad for SEO, it's more that crawlers don't (*or didn't*) process JS files so they generally couldn't see your client-side routes in a React SPA at all anyway. I *think* they've improved a bit though over time. It's why some create site-maps that are accessible from the root main page. That said, SEO is a bit of a black box anyway, and IMHO mostly guesswork on the "optimizer's" part.